# Is there any reason why i wouldnt be asked to update to new 16.04?

Tags: updates

I could just do it via usb but why the hassle if you don't have too, any reason why it wouldn't just be offering the update?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can always upate through terminal to the latest version:

You'll first need to make sure update-manager-core is present (it may already be installed):

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Next, run:
`sudo do-release-upgrade`

You may need to check `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and change the line:

```
Prompt=lts
```

to:

`Prompt=normal`

for the release to show up.

Comment: Op is not asking about how to upgrade, please take some time to re-read the question.